# Any clever way to distinguish inline-declared environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I want to distinguish between inline declared/defined environment variables exported to a child process and already existing/inherited envs.

```bsh
$ export NODEJS=8
$ FU=BAR sh -c 'echo $FU $NODEJS'
```

The specific use case is for cmd wrappers/decorators, where we **encapsulate** container usage (this is an example only).

```bsh
/tmp $ cat ./go.sh 
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

docker run \
    --rm \
    --volume $PWD:/opt/main \
    --workdir /opt/main \
golang:1.15 go "${@--h}"
```

```bsh
/tmp $ go version
go version go1.15.5 darwin/amd64
```

```bsh
/tmp $ mkdir -p /tmp/bin
/tmp $ ln -sf /tmp/go.sh /tmp/bin/go
/tmp $ chmod +x /tmp/go.sh 
/tmp $ PATH=/tmp/bin:$PATH
/tmp $ go version
Unable to find image 'golang:1.15' locally
1.15: Pulling from library/golang
756975cb9c7e: Pull complete 
d77915b4e630: Pull complete 
5f37a0a41b6b: Pull complete 
96b2c1e36db5: Pull complete 
145393847161: Pull complete 
3f8843661db9: Pull complete 
218d240e42d4: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0edb8df3d92a2ccf84d3245c8b0cc31edd6d23f9c3da3e07c8e2bd96eea34547
Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:1.15
go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64
```

I emphasized encapsulate, because to the end-user of the above wrapper script, there should be no difference, interface and/or expectation wise, whether we invoke from the Darwin host or the container. That means, no blank-slate envs like the following:

```bsh
/tmp $ env -i FU=BAR sh -c 'echo $FU $NODEJS'
BAR
```

To pass environment variables to docker runtime, I could do something like this:

```bsh
$ cat <<eof | head -n3
> docker run \
> --rm \
> --volume $PWD:/opt/main \
> --workdir /opt/main \
> $( env -0 | xargs -0 -L1 printf '--env "%s"\n' ) \
> golang:1.15 go "${@--h}"
> eof
docker run --rm --volume /tmp:/opt/main --workdir /opt/main --env "TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal"
--env "SHELL=/bin/bash"
--env "TERM=xterm-256color"
...
```

Which will break spectacularly when overwriting shell operating envs, like, um, `SHELL`, `PATH`, etc. We could use an additional manifest-y env, like ENVS, to whitelist which, um, envs to use, but that is problematic for a couple reasons.

```bsh
 $ cat /tmp/go.sh 
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

cat <<eof
docker run \
    --rm \
    --volume $PWD:/opt/main \
    --workdir /opt/main \
    $( echo $ENVS | xargs -n1 -- sh -c 'printf -- "--env %s=%s\n" $1 ${!1}' _) \
golang:1.15 go "${@--h}"
eof
$ ENVS="FU NODEJS" FU=BAR /tmp/go.sh 
docker run  --rm    --volume /tmp:/opt/main     --workdir /opt/main     --env FU=BAR
--env NODEJS=8 golang:1.15 go "-h"
```

First, its really messy and second, it violates the principle where the expected behavior of the wrapper should match that of the underlying target. If I pass envs to my go command, like the following, and they don't work, and it takes me a day to realize they need to specified in `ENVS`, Ill be less than thrilled.

```bsh
# fails to build appropriately targeted binary, but doesn't fail to build
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=ppc64 go build
```

```bsh
# this makes me mad
$ ENVS="GOOS GOARCH" GOOS=linux GOARCH=ppc64 go build
```

I don't know if there is any means of differently approaching this, other than obvious hardcoding, but if anyone has anything too-clever by half AND concise, I'd love to see it.

Comment: I just want to make sure - do you want to distinguish that `var=1 ./script.sh` from that `export var=1; ./script.sh`?

Comment: Parse `/proc/$PID/cmdline` and `/proc/$PPID/cmdline`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes - I dont care about precedence, just the ability to to discern inline declared envs; so in `export b=bbb; a=aaa ./script.sh argh` I am only concerned in determining if `a` was declared inline to the statement itself.

Comment: @waltinator not bad, but also not portable on Darwin at all, which really shouldn't be as much a concern as it is, but it is the default dev hardware for some reason.  Slightly adjusting your example, I could use environ and get the sym difference between parent and process. It's more work than I would care to do, but clever. Feel free to leave as answer if nothing else comes around.